# Set default value to option select menu

Tags: vue-component, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to bind a custom attribute to an option select menu.
The `<option>` tag would simply have an attribute of `selected="selected"`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <select>
      <option v-for="" v-bind:selected="[condition ? selected : notSelected]" value="">{{ resource.xprm_name }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

data: {
  selected: "selected",
  notSelected: ""
}
```

This does not work, but if I change `v-bind:selected` to `v-bind:class` then it receives the appropriate class, so the logic is working, but not with the `selected` attribute.

Any way to make it work with such custom attributes?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can just use `v-model` for selecting a default value on a select box:

Markup:

```
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected">
     <option value="foo">foo</option>
     <option value="bar">Bar</option>
     <option value="baz">Baz</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

View Model:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    selected: 'bar'
  }
});
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lxfxyqmf/

Comment: How can you use this in the `data(){} function`?  Nothing I have tried has worked and i have looked through several threads here on SO using several different ways and the VueJs2 docs.  [Select Basic Usage](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage)

Comment: @Chris22 Should just be `data: function () { return { selected: 'bar' } }`

Comment: How would you achieve this if you wanted to select the first index only. Ie. you don't know the results returned, so just auto-select the first result.

Answer (score 11):

html:

```html
<div id="myComponent">
    <select v-model="selectedValue">
        <option v-for="listValue in valuesList" :value="listValue">
            {{listValue}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <span>Chosen item: {{ selectedValue }}</span>
</div>
```

js:

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#myComponent',
    data: {
        selectedValue: 'Two',
        valuesList: ['One', 'Two', 'Three']
    },
```

Comment: This answer can be considered right when you simply want to have a value selected by default and don't want to use `v-model`.

Comment: @GustavoStraube Even if you use v-model, I dont see it selecting a default option. Using this along with v-model works in selecting a default

Answer (score 2):

I have created a reusable component of select that also emits the modelValue to parent component.

If you look at the first option tag, you can see how I create a default value using props.

**BaseSelect.vue (child component)**

```
<template>
  <label v-if="label">{{ label }}</label>
  <select
    class="field"
    :value="modelValue"
    v-bind="{
      ...$attrs,
      onChange: ($event) => {
        $emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value);
      },
    }"
  >
    <option value="" disabled>{{ defaultValue }}</option>
    <option
      v-for="option in options"
      :key="option"
      :value="option"
      :selected="option === modelValue"
    >
      {{ option }}
    </option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    label: {
      type: String,
      default: ""
    },
    defaultValue: {
      type: String,
      default: "Select an item of the list",
      required: false
    },
    modelValue: {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: "Otros"
    },
    options: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**Parent component**

```
<BaseSelect
      label="Asunto"
      defaultValue = "Selecciona un asunto" 
      v-model="contactValues.asunto"
      :options="asuntos"
    />
```

Notice that you have to receipt correctly this value in your data() (v-model)

Answer (score 0):

Using the new composition API:

```js
<template>
     <select v-model="selectValue">
         <option value="a">
             Option a
         </option>
         <option value="b">
             Option b
         </option>
      </select>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default {
    setup() {
        // Create a reactive value for our select
        const selectValue = ref('a');

        // Return to the template
        return { selectValue };
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: The question is tagged Vue2 (although technically the composition API can be used with that version)