# Using Vuetify, how to set a default value in v-select?

Tags: vue.js

I have two completely unrelated tables and I want to get the options (dropdown items) from table 1 and then post the option to table 2. This is pretty easy since I can use: items to get items from table 1, however, I'm using the v-model to bind the data to table 2 so I can't use it to display a default from table 1. Is there any other way to do this?

What I have:

```
<v-select>
:items="table1"
v-model="table2"
</v-select>
```

Essentially is there a way to do this:

```
<v-select>
:items="table1"
v-model="table2" - connect to db
v-model="table1[1]"  - set default selected value
</v-select>
```

Comment: no, you have to manipulate in data block, and bind that variable in v-select

Comment: I hope you had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41122028/set-default-value-to-option-select-menu). This should solve the problem.

Comment: 1. As in create a pivot table? 2.I've taken a look at the question listed but it doesn't solve the problem since I'm not specifying options manually, I'm getting the items from a db table and from my understanding select has different attributes to v-select so I can't use the option tag

Comment: is this vuetify? if so, what is `:option`? shouldn't it be `:items`?

Comment: Yes, sorry you're right, it is :items

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve], best would be a demo, you can find predone here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects Since at least I have some questions. Are these arrays, are these array of primitives or objects, is this a multiple? etc.....